# Rails Migrations or Manual Database creation?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm a newbie to Rails and just started writing my first application in Rails.

Now, i have a question on which i need some advice. Should i go ahead with Rails Migrations for generating the database tables or should i stick to the old MySQL way of creating each table manually.

What's your say?? What way proves to be a better choice eventually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be the only one different with a differing opinion here, but I usually have a pretty darn good idea of what my structure is going to look like. So I usually start with a fairly complete `schema.rb` file. I can then load the schema (`rake db:schema:load`) to set up my database structure. My migrations then track modifications from that original schema.

A good quality database design is important, even in RoR.

Either way, though, I think we'll all agree that you schema, either in `schema.rb` or lots of migrations, needs to be part of your Rails application.

Comment: That's a totally good way to do it. One of the greatest benefits of migrations comes from tracking changes to your schema. I tend to start from scaffolds (https://github.com/beardedstudio/scaffolder) to prototype quickly. The best part is that both approaches are completely Rails-y.

Comment: Thanks `Jarret` that was well explained. One of my other query that was somehow related to this one was answered by someone in one of my threads and now i'm more clear and move forward towards developing in Rails.

Comment: Just one more small question though, where would i find this Schema.rb file in my Rails application?

Comment: It's under RAILS_ROOT/db/schema.rb

Answer (score 0):

Definitely Migrations. There is a reason why it is in there. It is databasesystem independent, highly flexible and consistent to use within Rails

Answer (score 0):

As is often the case when working with Rails, "convention over configuration" is the way to go. The migration system is in place to allow to you abstract your model away from your database, and makes your project far more portable.

By using migrations, you are making sure that your application always knows about your database in a clear and consistent way, and you make it easy for others to add to and extend your application in a manner that is easier to merge back in later.